# Eclipse, don't share Tabs between JAVA EE and Javascript perspectives

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I'm developing a web application, that uses JavaScript and Java.

So in the **perspective of Java EE I don't want to see the tabs of Javascript**, and in the **perspective Javascript don't want to see Java tabs**.

But eclipse shares the tab container between them.
(And if I drop my javascript tab to other container, this solves the problem for a while. But when I open other file it open's in the default tab container)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If I knew I would not be asking, but such feature would be helpful.

Comment: The eclipse forums and issue trackers might be a better location to source an answer for information on this

Comment: I will try to ask if this is possible on the eclipse forum

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new window and use both perspectives at the same time.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: The OP is asking how to make eclipse open files in a perspective instead of another, based on the file type. This does not answer the question.